# FullScreen Notification

Tags: android

I want to create a full screen notification.I have achieved a notification by using the following code. What changes do i need to make it a full screen notification.

```
    private void showNotification(String data) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Test")
            .setContentText(data)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(0,builder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can convert simple notification to full screen notification just added a simple line of code `builder.setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true);` following is full example. I hope this code help you

### Full Screen Notification Code:

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star);
        builder.setContentTitle("This is title of notification");
        builder.setContentText("This is a notification Text");
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

        Intent intent = new Intent(Broadcastdemo.this, ThreadDemo.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 113,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        builder.setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true);


        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(115, builder.build());
```

Comment: yes, this should be the correct answer. It still works on Android 10 (beta 6)

Answer (score 1):

On your builder, just before `setContentIntent(pendingIntent);`
Simply add the following line: `.setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true);`

Answer (score 0):

try to add both `setStyle` and `setPriority` as the following: (it is working fine for me)

```
  .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().BigText(message.Long_Message))   
  .setPriority((int)NotificationPriority.Max)
```